# jQueryUI droppable alert when dropped - keyboard focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, counter, droppable

I can get this to work using the mouse. I can't get it to work using the keyboard.

This works and adds a message when dropped using the mouse:

```
$('.drop_01').droppable ({
    drop: function() {
        $('span.movedItem1').remove();
        $(this).prepend('<span class=\"movedItem1\">Item moved to Program philisophy drop area Vision/mission.</span>');
    }
});
```

I need to have the same happen when using the keyboard combination Alt+1. I have this and tried several variations but cannot get it to work. The item still moves to the dropped position but the message does not display.

```
$(".activity").on("keydown", "#activity_contents a", function (e) {
if(e.altKey && ( e.which === 49 )) {

$('.drop_01').droppable ({
    drop: function() {
        $('span.movedItem1').remove();
        $(this).prepend('<span class=\"movedItem1\">Item moved to Program philisophy drop area Vision/mission.</span>');
    }
});

}
});
```

If this is achievable can someone help please. To clarify this is just to display the message the drag/drop function is a lot of additional code not posted.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this the wrong way. The solution I have (although a bit untidy) is:

```
// CtRL key moves something to next column
$(".activity").on("keydown", ".connected-sortable.draggable li", function (event) {
    var $this = $(this)
        , key = event.keyCode || e.which
        , $holder = $this.parents(".activity")
        , $selectedul = $this.parent()
        , $availableuls = $holder.find(".connected-sortable")
        , currentlistindex = $selectedul.data("list-index")
        , nextlistindex = currentlistindex + 1
        , $nextul = $holder.find(".connected-sortable[data-list-index='" + nextlistindex + "']")
        , $originalul = $holder.find(".connected-sortable[data-list-index='0']");

    if ($nextul.length == 0) {
        $nextul = $originalul;

    }

    if(nextlistindex === 1) {
        $('span.movedItema').remove();
        $('span.movedItemb').remove();
        $('span.movedItemc').remove();
        $('span.movedItemd').remove();
        $(this).focus().prepend('<span class=\"movedItema offscreenText\">Item moved to Program philisophy drop area Vision/mission.</span>');
    }
    if(nextlistindex === 2) {
        $('span.movedItema').remove();
        $('span.movedItemb').remove();
        $('span.movedItemc').remove();
        $('span.movedItemd').remove();
        $(this).focus().prepend('<span class=\"movedItemb offscreenText\">Item moved to Program philisophy drop area Beliefs/values.</span>');
    }
    if(nextlistindex === 3) {
        $('span.movedItema').remove();
        $('span.movedItemb').remove();
        $('span.movedItemc').remove();
        $('span.movedItemd').remove();
        $(this).focus().prepend('<span class=\"movedItemc offscreenText\">Item moved to Program philisophy drop area Strategies.</span>');
    }
    if(nextlistindex === 4) {
        $('span.movedItema').remove();
        $('span.movedItemb').remove();
        $('span.movedItemc').remove();
        $('span.movedItemd').remove();
        $(this).focus().prepend('<span class=\"movedItemd offscreenText\">Item moved back to Program philisophy Factors list.</span>');
    }
```